# How do I buy or add Hull?

Tags: nimbatus

I made the mistake to sell the Hull.

I tried going to the shop that some systems have but apparently they don't sell it there.

Is there a way to replace it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one type of shop. One of them is "Garage".

At the Garage you can buy Hull or sell Hull.